# Finding best match by minMaxLoc returned values OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, template-matching

I have one source picture and 5 other samples and I want to find the sample that matches the source image best. I concluded that should use template matching since histogram comparison didn't fit the problem well. I use `cv::minMaxLoc` to determine min and max values of the result matrix but I misunderstand how to compare this values to properly find the "best-matching" picture.
Thank you!

PS: I have read OpenCV documentation.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's a tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) explaining the use of `cv::matchTemplate()`. In addition to the min and max, [`cv::MinMaxLoc()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#minmaxloc) returns the top-left corner of the template position for the best match.

Note that if you expect more than one max/min then `cv::MinMaxLoc()` is not sufficient since it returns only a single point.

Comment: what about min and max value

Comment: Please see the docs for `cv::MinMaxLoc()` here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#minmaxloc

Comment: I think this is not an acceptable answer. The user ask distances between template and sources. She wants to select most similar source.